# selects and POST

Tags: php, select, post

I've build a little quick and generic pair of select for my month and year for card payments. if goes a little something like this:

```
<select name="expire_month" class="mand">
    <?for($month=1;$month<=12;$month++){
        echo"<option value='".$month."'>".str_pad($month,2,"0",STR_PAD_LEFT)."</option>";
    }?>
</select>
<select name="expire_year" class="mand">
    <?
    for($year=date('Y');$year<=((int)date('Y')+5);$year++){
        echo"<option value='".$year."'>".$year."</option>";
    }?>
</select>
```

How can I incorporate a $_POST value into this? So that when a user selects an option, the same option will be selected when returning to the form?

Comment: Please add some php code which handles the POST of the form

Comment: When returning to the form you would likely want to do one of two things, read the values from a cookie or read the values from a database.

Comment: just using $_POST. Don't want to save any card details at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your form processing code do like this:-

```
$_SESSION['selected_month'] = $_POST['selected_month'];
$_SESSION['selected_year']  = $_POST['selected_year'];
```

Try like this:-

```
<select name="expire_month" class="mand">
    <?for($month=1;$month<=12;$month++){
        if(isset($_SESSION['selected_month']) && $month == $_SESSION['selected_month']){
            echo"<option  selected='selected' value='".$month."'>".str_pad($month,2,"0",STR_PAD_LEFT)."</option>" . "\n";
        }else{
        echo"<option value='".$month."'>".str_pad($month,2,"0",STR_PAD_LEFT)."</option>" . "\n";
    }}?>
</select>
<select name="expire_year" class="mand">
    <?
    for($year=date('Y');$year<=((int)date('Y')+5);$year++){
        if(isset($_SESSION['selected_year']) && $year == $_SESSION['selected_year']){
            echo"<option  selected='selected' value='".$year."'>".$year."</option>" . "\n";
        }else{
        echo"<option value='".$year."'>".$year."</option>" . "\n";
    }}?>
</select>
```

**NOTE:- `$_POST['selected_month'], $_POST['selected_year']` are the values that you are selected through form already and you have to set it either in `session` or `cookie` and then put in code.**

Comment: `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file` - 2 missing braces. Edit: as per original answer http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/30595874/1

Comment: @Fred-ii- you are always helpful for me. thanks to be do helpful and not too rude. thanks

Comment: what if the user forgets to select value and submits the form ? You should be handling those scenarios also :)

Comment: it's his responsibility to check that not ours.

Comment: @kirshna I can do that myself :p I'll either put in a default option or because I'm using paypal i could just use error 400 when checking for incorrect details but bit pointless sending curls.

Comment: @sourRaspberri i hope you get solution?

Comment: @anantkumarsingh Yes thanks, I can work from this. Basically just needed to know the attribute selected. lol now I can keep going. thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

```
<?PHP 
    $post_month = $_POST['expire_month'];
    $post_year = $_POST['expire_year'];

?>
<select name="expire_month" class="mand">
    <?for($month=1;$month<=12;$month++){ ?>
        <option value='<?PHP echo $month?>' <?PHP if($post_month == $month) { echo "selected"; } ?>><?PHP echo str_pad($month,2,"0",STR_PAD_LEFT);?></option>
   <? }?>
</select>
<select name="expire_year" class="mand">
    <?
    for($year=date('Y');$year<=((int)date('Y')+5);$year++){ ?>
       <option value='<?PHP echo $year?>' <?PHP if($post_year == $year) { echo "selected"; } ?>><?PHP echo $year; ?></option>
    <?}?>
</select>
```

Comment: I didn't know there was a selected attribute! Thanks! Simple enough really XD haha

Comment: What if the `$_POST` array isn't set?

Comment: `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '}', expecting ',' or ';'` - Edit: as per original answer http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/30595809/1

Comment: you should be using `isset()` before directly saving POST values

Comment: why should they accept it? your code has syntax errors.

Comment: @JayBlanchard then default will be "00". I could use `$_SESSION` in the same way.

Comment: @vishalshah thanks for your answer! It was hard to decide so I decided keeping in mind code structure. Sorry!

Answer (score 0):

you can use your posted data and check a condition in loop if it got matched the set selected attribute to the option here is the example

```
<?php $selected_option=$_POST['expire_month']; ?>

<select name="expire_month" class="mand">

<?php for($month=1;$month<=12;$month++){

 if($selected_option==$month){

 echo"<option value='".$month."' selected='selected'>".str_pad($month,2,"0",STR_PAD_LEFT)."</option>";}


else{ echo"<option value='".$month."' >".str_pad($month,2,"0",STR_PAD_LEFT)."</option>";
}}?>
```